# String.Replace doesn't work with a php file?

Tags: c#, .net

Why the code below doesnt work ?

```
      string Tmp_actionFilepath = @"Temp\myaction.php";


       // change the id and the secret code in the php file
            File.Copy(@"Temp\settings.php", Tmp_actionFilepath, true);
            string ActionFileContent = File.ReadAllText(Tmp_actionFilepath);
            string unique_user_id = textBox5.Text.Trim();
            string secret_code = textBox1.Text.Trim();
            ActionFileContent.Replace("UNIQUE_USER_ID", unique_user_id);
            ActionFileContent.Replace("SECRET_CODE", secret_code);
            File.WriteAllText(Tmp_actionFilepath, ActionFileContent);
```

Here is the content of setting.php

```
      <?php
      session_start();
      $_SESSION["postedData"] = $_POST;

      /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
      $_SESSION["uid"] = "UNIQUE_USER_ID";
      $_SESSION["secret"] = "SECRET_CODE";
      /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

      function findThis($get){
      $d = '';
      for($i = 0; $i < 30; $i++){
      if(file_exists($d.$get)){
        return $d;
      }else{
        $d.="../";
      }
    }
  }


   $rootDir = findThis("root.cmf");

   require_once($rootDir."validate_insert.php");
```

What is wrong with the code above ? After compiling the code in c#, i noticed the file myaction.php is created, but the values : UNIQUE_USER_ID and SECRET_CODE doesn't change, I tried also to copy/paste these values to make sure they are same. But the code always doesn't work

Answer (score 5):

[`String.Replace`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.replace.aspx) returns a new string as strings are immutable. It does not replace the string you are calling it on.

You should replace:

```
ActionFileContent.Replace("UNIQUE_USER_ID", unique_user_id);
ActionFileContent.Replace("SECRET_CODE", secret_code);
```

with:

```
ActionFileContent = ActionFileContent.Replace("UNIQUE_USER_ID", unique_user_id);
ActionFileContent = ActionFileContent.Replace("SECRET_CODE", secret_code);
```

On top of that you should really change your variable names so they follow the regular C# naming conventions (i.e. use `actionFileContent` instead of `ActionFileContent`).

Answer (score 2):

you have to set the result of the `replace` string method on a string.

```
string Tmp_actionFilepath = @"Temp\myaction.php";

// change the id and the secret code in the php file
File.Copy(@"Temp\settings.php", Tmp_actionFilepath, true);

string actionFileContent = File.ReadAllText(Tmp_actionFilepath);

string unique_user_id = textBox5.Text.Trim();
string secret_code = textBox1.Text.Trim();

// set the result of the Replace method on the string.
actionFileContent = ActionFileContent.Replace("UNIQUE_USER_ID", unique_user_id)
                                     .Replace("SECRET_CODE", secret_code);

File.WriteAllText(Tmp_actionFilepath, actionFileContent);
```